# Automatically change a value in a form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a webpage where people enter information (name, job title, address, etc.) and it auto creates a business card for them. I currently have some jQuery that uses .change and looks at a field when a user changes it.

It looks for issues with what they enter, because some things must be in a certain format (ex- They enter the word "Avenue" and it won't let them add the item to their cart until they change it to Ave.)

I am trying to find some way to do this on the fly automatically with JS/jQuery, but I'm not sure what to do. What I would like is for the field to update itself, so if the user puts in "Avenue" it would auto update to "Ave." after the user tabs / exits the field.

Any idea on what JS and/or jQuery can be used to do this?

Here is my current code:

```
 var x = "Clean";
 var xD = "&nbsp;";
 $('#cartText4046').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf("Avenue") > -1) {
            x = "Please use Ave. instead of Avenue.";
        } else if ($(this).val().indexOf("avenue") > -1) {
            x = "Please use Ave. instead of Avenue.";
        ... Additional rules here, omitted for space.
        } else {
           x = "Clean";
        }


    if (x != "Clean") {
        $('#cartText4046').addClass("invalid");
        xD = x;
     } else if (x == "Clean") {
        $('#cartText4046').removeClass("invalid");
        xD = "&nbsp;";
    }

     if (x != "Clean") {
        $('.betabutton').html('<span id="addToBaskettext">To add this to the Basket, 
         please fix the following issue(s):<br><br>&nbsp;' +xD'</span>');
        $('.betabutton').addClass("invalidBtn");
     } else if (x == "Clean") {
        $('.betabutton').html('<a id="addToBasket" href="#" onclick="actionPageSubmit();return false;"><span id="addToBaskettext">Add to Basket</span></a>');
        $('.betabutton').removeClass("invalidBtn");
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code you have.

Comment: @j08691 I don't have any, I'm looking for suggestions on what to use. I can post the code that looks at the field to see if something is entered incorrectly, but I'm trying to move away from that to something does it automatically, so I don't think it's relevant to the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tour "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat." You'll get better responses if you try something and post your results.

Comment: @mkaatman thanks, I'll be sure to read up on that link!

Comment: So you do not know how to use `val("new value")` and replace the text in a textbox?

Comment: @epascarello I don't know how to use `val()` to replace just the one incorrect string of text while leaving the rest intact. I'm not the greatest with JS

Comment: [MDN `replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: @epascarello I think this will work, thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working sample of what you may be looking for.

```
$("#textbox").on("change", function() {
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
        return value.replace('Avenue', 'Ave.');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/decx8sw9/

Comment: this works great and even accepts periods unlike the js.autocorrect I have been trying to set up. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted it to do it after the user has finished making changes ("after the user tabs / exits the field.") you might want to bind to blur (fires when focus is lost/shifted to some other element)...

```
$('#cartText4046').on( "blur", function() {
$(this).val(function(index, value) {
    value = value.replace('Avenue', 'Ave.');
    // keep going ... value = value.replace('Street', 'St.') ..
    return value;
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but this isn't really any different than the accepted answer except for the event handler difference.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I reread the question, and now see that you wanted the correction to happen after the user exits the field. This answer provides inline autocorrection while the user types. I will leave it in case you find it useful after all.

You can lift the code from the [jQuery Autocorrect Plugin](https://github.com/sanisoft/jQuery-auto-correct/blob/master/jquery.autocorrect.js): [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6txvrn0/).

```
$("#textbox").autocorrect({
    corrections: {
        Avenue: "Ave.",
        "...": "someWord"
    }
});
```

Comment: This is super helpful. Thank you. It does exactly what I need, but with one issue (the word to be corrected doesn't accept periods, but I am trying to find a way to make it accept them)

Comment: It will accept periods if you put the key (word to be corrected) in quotes. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I couldn't get a string of text to work in it, for example "Pharm D" needs to go to "PharmD"

Comment: Oh, okay, I think you mean spaces? The example with periods works in the fiddle.

Comment: yep a string of text with spaces. The periods do work in the fiddle, so that was one issue solved, but I need to be able to also do text with spaces which doesn't work when put in quotes.

Comment: Correct, the autocorrect function uses the spacebar key to start correction, and uses the space character to split the entered text into words to be tested. Therefore you would have to change the function significantly in order to test for keys which include spaces. I think you have better options.